# Audit Script function.sample inquiry?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on an audit script that is supposed to to take a 1, 3, or 5% sample from each category in a dataframe, unless 1% is less than 3--then it provides 3 samples. The issue is is that the categories change depending on the excel file. the syntax for taking a sample from a certain category explained above is as follows:

```
df2.groupby('Category')['shoe'].apply(lambda X: x.sample(n=3) if x.size*0.01 
< 3 else x.sample(frac=0.01))
```

The issue is that I want to loop through every category in the read file, and sample it. Finally, combing it into one dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\***\Desktop\***.xlsx")

df2 = df.loc[(df['Track Item']=='Y')]
print(len(df2))

categories = df2['Category'].unique
subcategories = dfs['Subcategory'].unique

def sample_per(df2):
    if len(df2) >= 15000:
        return df2.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=3) if x.size*0.01 < 3 else 
        x.sample(frac=0.01))
    elif len(df2) < 15000 and len(df2) > 10000:
        return df2.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=3) if x.size*0.03 < 3 else 
        x.sample(frac=0.03))
    else:
        return df2.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=3) if x.size*0.05 < 3 else 
        x.sample(frac=0.05))

final = sample_per(df2)

df.loc[df['Retailer Item ID'].isin(final['Retailer Item ID']), 'Track Item'] 
= 'Audit'

df.to_csv('Test_2.csv',index=False)
```

The code works, but it only brings back either 1, 3, or 5% of the entire file, not those percentages from each category. Any help would be appreciated. *the spacing is a little off because the lines don't fit in the box)

I have also tried the following, to try and loop through all categories:

```
return (df2.groupby('Category')[lambda x: x in categories].apply(lambda x: 
x.sample(n=3) if x.size*0.01 < 3 else x.sample(frac=0.01)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `unique` to `unique()`.
Try these edits to `sample_per`: Keep the `apply` functions. Add a `category` param. Replace `df2.groupby('Category')` with `df2.loc[df2.Category == category, :]`. Check that `sample_per` works for a category. Then you can use it in a loop for all categories in `categories`. Good job.

Comment: Thank you!  the line--df2.loc[df2.Category == category, :]-- category should be categories, right? As categories is the unique list of categories?

Comment: should it be: 
    return (df2.loc[df2.Category == categories, :]).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=3) if 
    x.size*0.01 < 3 else x.sample(frac=0.01))